# JAXB unmarshalling returning empty object

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

JAXB unmarshalling of a XML file into objects works fine when run in testng unit testcase.

When the same code is used to unmarshall the same XML file in another process, I am getting an empty object. I could verify that objects are getting created for every element in the XML document and all the adapters are getting called. Set the event handler in unmarshaller but there were no validation issues. When I set the xmlns attribute and the prefix, the behavior was slightly different even though empty object is returned.

I saw several posts but could not relate with the problem I am facing.

Please suggest where I should start looking for the problem. Is it mandatory to specify schema when unmarshalling?

Answer (score 1):

The cause is mentioned in this post: [JAXB does not call Setter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664152/jaxb-does-not-call-setter-method).

Confirmed that the get method for the list is getting called and is populated.

Replaced the list with an array and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

The beauty of JAXB is it doesnot call the setter and it uses the same `List` from ther getter. In case of generating JAXB classes from XSD; you can even notice that the elements with `maxOccurs=unbound required=true` will not have a setter at all.